# How to change request header "Host" while running unit tests?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

Trying to change request header 'Host' value while running a unit test but it gets changed back to the original value defined in phpunit.xml

Is there a way to override this value for one test only?

```
/**
 * Throw an exception if host value is not matching
 * trusted host patterns.
 * @group debug
 */
public function testErrorReturnedOnUnmatchedHostValue()
{
    $this->withHeaders([
        'Host' => 'http://google.com',
    
    ])
        ->get('/')
        ->assertStatus(500);
}
```

I have tried the following:

- Change the environment variable using putenv('APP_URL=http://google.com')
- Tried setting up headers in the setUp() method

But the value gets changed back to original url (which is defined in .env).

Any ideas would be appreciated?

Comment: Try changing the config in `setUp` e.g. `config([ 'app.url' => ... ])` since that's where `APP_URL` ends up in anyway

Comment: Try to avoid doing `putenv` or similar, as it will change the value for all the tests, and reverting will look horrible, there are other solutions, but it is strange you want to test changing the `host`, as you only use `.env` to do so (it looks like that), why are you testing this ?

Answer (score 1):

The `HOST` cannot be set via `withHeaders` and `HTTP_HOST` cannot be set using `withServerVariables`. However, you can set it using the `URL` facade and then set it back at the end of your test. Below are the pieces, feel free to place in the test/setUp/tearDown:

```
$original_url = URL::current();
URL::forceRootUrl('http://my.domain.com');
... call $this->get/post etc
URL::forceRootUrl($original_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to change the host header is by simply adding the domain itself to the URI.

```php
$response = $this->get("http://google.com/");
```

You probably want to have a route for that as well to test things out? Here's how to do that I took it to extreme levels by adding a random domain using faker.

```php
$domain = $this->faker->domainName;
Route::domain($domain)->get('/ping', function() {
    return 'pong';
});
$response = $this->get("http://$domain/ping");
```